# When opening a new Qt project and adding one file to it, no content within the files

Tags: c++, qt

Hwy guys.
Im new to Qt, and I encountered a problen in the begining.

I opened new project with the properties:
`Desktop Qt 5.7.1 MSVC2013 64bit`

And opened for my project, a new `main.cpp` file.
Thw tutorial sayes:

```
there is some minimal code that should always be written :

TEMPLATE = app
TARGET = name_of_the_app

QT = core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets
```

And:

```
The minimal source code of a Qt application is

#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
 QApplication app (argc, argv);
 return app.exec();
}
```

But the both file (`.pro`, and `.cpp`) have no cintent within it. its empty!
So I added by myself the content from the site, and just changed the version `4` to be the real one.
Buy still, I geting the next problem:

> 12:50:48: Could not determine which "make" command to run. Check the
>   "make" step in the build configuration. Error while building/deploying
>   project untitled (kit: Desktop Qt 5.7.1 MSVC2013 64bit) When executing
>   step "qmake"

Im lost, and I want to learn already how to use it. please guys. some help will be greatful.

EDIT:
This is the image shown the Error I have:
 [Error compiler](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4TsCh.png)

I know what compiler should do, but I did never mess with that.
What compiler I should download from the internet, and how do I connect between it and the Qt?

Comment: I suggest you reinstall the latest version of Qt from scratch.

Comment: @I will... But maybe the problen is on the installation. So I preffer to wait to an answer before I redone the same mistake

Comment: If you are using Qt Creator, can you go to "Tools > Options > Build & Run" and check for any warning or error ?

Comment: @BenjaminT I edit the content. What should I do with that error? BTW thanks for advencing me with the situation..

Comment: @linkGo It seems you don't have MSVC 2013 compiler installed. So you have to install it.